# Laravel: Eloquent returning an object I can't iterate over

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a mySQL DB schema like this:

```
table RECIPES:

int id, PK;
int salesman_id;
int doctor_id;
date order_date;
int status;

table RECIPE_STATUS:

int id, PK;
int recipe_status_code;
varchar recipe_status_name;
```

In Laravel I have the following php classes:

```html
AdminRecipesController.php

namespace RatCMS\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use RatCMS\Models\Recipes;
use RatCMS\Models\RecipeStatus;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class AdminRecipesController extends Controller
{
   
    public function index()
    {

        $recipes = Recipes::with('recipeStatus')->get();
        
        return view('admin.recipes.news', compact('recipes'));

    }

}



Recipes.php


<?php

namespace RatCMS\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Recipes extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'RECIPES';

    protected $fillable = ['salesman_id', 'doctor_id', 'order_date', 'status'];

    public function recipeStatus() {
        return $this->hasOne(\RatCMS\Models\RecipeStatus::class, 'recipe_status_code', 'status');
    }

}



RecipeStatus.php


<?php

namespace RatCMS\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RecipeStatus extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'RECIPE_STATUS';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function recipes() {
        return $this->belongsTo(\RatCMS\Models\Recipes::class);
    }

}


blade view

<div class="box-body">
            @include('admin.partials.session_success')

            @if($recipes->isEmpty())
                <p class="text-center">No recipes available.</p>
            @else

                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                        <th>Salesman</th>
                        <th>Doctor</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th style="width:100px">Actions</th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach($recipes as $recipe)
                        {{ $recipe }}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $recipe->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $recipe->salesman_id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $recipe->doctor_id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $recipe->order_date }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $recipe->recipe_status->recipe_status_name }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <form style="display: inline-block" action="{{ url('admin/recipes/' . $recipe->id) }}" method="POST">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>

            @endif


        </div>
```

When I do `{{ $recipe }}` in the view, I get the following result:

{"id":1,"salesman_id":"4","doctor_id":"3","order_date":null,"status":"0","recipe_status":{"id":1,"recipe_status_code":"0","recipe_status_name":"Not Recieved"}}

so there is some data being return by Eloquent regarding the recipe status (Not Recieved text), but when I do `{{ $recipe->recipe_status }}` it fails every time. Even $recipes['recipe_status'] is no help.

Could someone help? Thanks

Comment: try by changing your status to a valid integer like 1,2,3 and corresponding recipe_status_code and the check the result

Comment: What about `{{ $recipe->recipe_status->recipe_status_name }}`? `$recipe->recipe_status` is an object!

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object..

Comment: non-object? what do you see with `dd($recipe->recipe_status);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationship should be `belongsTo()`:

```
public function recipeStatus() {
    return $this->belongsTo(\RatCMS\Models\RecipeStatus::class, 'status', 'recipe_status_code');
}
```

With correct relationship your code will add relationship data to collection, so you'll be able to get status:

```
$recipe->recipeStatus->recipe_status_name
```

Comment: That's fine but that's not answering my question

Comment: Well, your question is why relationship is empty. With correct relationship definition your code will return iteratable relationship data.

Comment: Whether I use belongsTo() or hasOne(), the result is the same, I can't view recipe_status in $recipe

Comment: Did you copy pasted my code or just changed relation? Did you try code from my answer to display status code name? Because `recipe_status` will not work anyway. Show appropriate migrations please.

Comment: Thanks, the $recipe->recipeStatus annotation was what I was missing! Thanks a lot!